# How was the vector magnitude derived?

Tags: vectors

The magnitude of a $n$-vector is defined as:
$$
\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2}
$$
or for those that prefer sigma notation:
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}
$$
How would this have been derived? Or was this one of those cases where mathematicians went trial-by-error to find a formula that seemed to work and then proved it later?

Comment: It is repeated generalization of the Pythagorean Theorem.  The length of the vector is the hypoteneuse.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I was thinking about the Pythagorean Theorem but I thought about it as, the use of the magnitude formula on a $2$-vector (the hypotenuse) is (yet another) proof for Pythagoras.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork When you say it is generalized, do you mean to say that, as I suggested, they probably did a trial-and-error run on vectors with more components, see that, "oh, look at that, it also works in 3D too," then just later make a proof for it, as opposed to a formula being derived from something else?

Comment: No "trial and error."  *NEVER* trial and error!!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I didn't so much mean it in terms of "oh, it's worked for all situations so far, that's proof then." More along the lines of people noticing patterns in mathematics, examining them and creating a formula that seems to work for it, then actually proving it. If they can prove the formula, the method of how they came up with the formula doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a vector $[a_1]\in\mathbb{R}$, the magnitude is obviously $\sqrt{a_1^2}=|a_1|$. For a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, using pythagros, the magnitude is $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$. Then for a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, consider the image:

[image]

In this case, $x=a_1$, $y=a_2$ and $z=a_3$. The length by pythagoras of $AC$ is $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$. Using pythagroas again to find AB, the magnitude of out vector, we get:

$$AB=\sqrt{AC^2+a_3^2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}^2+a_3^2}=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}$$

Similarly for $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^4$, we get:

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}^2+a_3^2}^2+a_4^2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}^2+a_4^2}=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2}$$

While this doesn't provide a rigorous proof for an n-dimensional formula in the euclidean metric, it provides some intuition into how you generalise the Pythagorean formula to dimensions higher than 2. You can prove the general case with induction, which I will leave to you if you want. I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Just try labelling the lengths of each of the vectors here and you'll answer the question for yourself:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I think I see. The x-y plane vector (bottom blue) has a particular magnitude and it can have the z-component added to it to raise it (making the main vector) and then you have a triangle formed with the main vector as the hypotenuse and the z-compenent and blue-vector's magnitude. Yeah?